# Find rows with similar date values

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I want to find customers where for example, system by error registered duplicates of an order.

It's pretty easy, if reg_date is EXACTLY the same but I have no idea how to implement it in query to count as duplicate if for example there was up to 1 second difference between transactions.

```
select * from
(select customer_id, reg_date, count(*) as cnt

 from orders

group by 1,2

) x where cnt > 1
```

Here is example dataset:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m6PhgReSQbVWVZhqe8n4mi/0

CUrrently only customer's 104 orders are counted as duplicates because its reg_date is identical, I want to count also orders 1,2 and 4,5 as there's just 1 second difference

Comment: Can you share the structure of the table and an example of 2 lines that have to be considered duplicated?

Comment: You are looking for duplicates from the same day?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Description updated, link to db fiddle included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=a2cf690361e0bcf7ab6d8d73e572310e)

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    reg_date
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        reg_date - lag(reg_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY reg_date) <= interval '1 second' as is_duplicate
    FROM
        orders
) s
WHERE is_duplicate
```

Use the `lag()` [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/tutorial-window.html). It allows to have a look hat the previous record. With this value you can do a diff and filter the records where the diff time is more than one second.

Comment: I forgot to add I'm using postgresql 9.4

Comment: Ok, created another query

Comment: Although you're getting 3-values in `is_duplicate`, since you have to contend with `NULL` values from the `LAG` function. It might be better to wrap it in a `CASE` expression. It might also be a bit clearer to use an intermediate CTE (that was my initial thought anyways).

Comment: @Zack What do you mean? When there are any NULL values they will be filtered within the WHERE clause (see fiddle with intermediate step). For what do you want to create a CTE? Which benefits?

Comment: You're right about the `NULL` values being discarded by the `WHERE` clause---I was thinking of the expression `reg_date - lag(reg_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY reg_date) <= interval '1 second'` generating `NULLs` for the "first" order per customer (although it's a moot point anyways). I was thinking a CTE might make things a bit clearer, as opposed to using a sub-query and 98-column expression (not counting the alias), but that might just be a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Zack You have to be careful using CTEs because they may be slower for several reasons. In this case they are not that much slower but a tiny bit: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=5533fa7bf79b7c2e5a37b7f7d19bf6f1

Comment: @s-man Thank you so much, that's exacly what I needed, nice workaround in case of missing features from newer postgresql :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this following script. This will return you day/customer wise duplicates.

```
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(reg_date :: DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') reg_date,
customer_id, 
count(*) as cnt
FROM orders
GROUP BY 
TO_CHAR(reg_date :: DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
customer_id
HAVING count(*) >1
```

Comment: This will not work if both timestamps would be over the day change